# Kendo Grid ClientTemplate conditional column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, conditional-statements, kendo-grid, client-templates

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4 with Kendo UI(kendo grid).Below is sample code of Kendo Grid -

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Users).Name("Grid").Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
   columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
   columns.Bound(p => p.UserName);
   columns.Bound(p => p.Email);   
   columns.Bound(o => o.IsActive).ClientTemplate(links).Title("Action");      

})
```

> > In the above code my IsActive column have some links for Actions like Edit,Update,Delete.And i am adding those links into Kendo grid by links variable.And I want to  use links variable on the basis of conditions.Means i want conditional ClientTemplate here.

So anyone suggest how can make a conditional ClientTemplate in kendoGrid ?

2) Also i want to add condition on the basis on the bool field value of my model(Model.Users).

So i want to know how we can get that field from Model.Users model in kendo grid for each row.Like -

```
.ClientTemplate(if(IsAdmin && ViewBag.IsActive){.....} else{....})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like below code..may be this help you..

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Active).ClientTemplate("\\#if('#=Active#'=='Y') {\\<input type='button' value='OK' />\\}\\#");
```

or may be use

```
"#= (Active) ? ' ' : 'your code here' #"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply #Parthiv.But according to my need i have to add one more condition in that template query.And that condition will be based on some other server variable.So can you suggest me how we can add that ?

Comment: Hey Pawan, You are absolutely right but you can maintain this IsAdmin flag in ViewBag and access in this ClientTemplate.or whatever values you can maintaing in viewbag and access it.

Comment: @ParthivPandya Parthiv - can you help on this similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334924/kendo-grid-clienttemplate-if-else-condition

Comment: .ClientTemplate("# if(data.TotalSalesAmt.sum == 0) " +
                                           "{# <div>Avg: #= kendo.toString(0,'P2') # </div>#} " +
                                           "else {# <div>Avg: #= kendo.toString(data.TotalMarginAmt.sum / data.TotalSalesAmt.sum,'P2') # </div> #}#") try this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following piece of code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Users).Name("Grid").Columns(columns =>
{
  columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
  columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
  columns.Bound(p => p.UserName);
  columns.Bound(p => p.Email);   
  columns.Bound(o => o.IsActive).ClientTemplate("#if(IsActive){#<a href='javascript:void(0)' >Edit</a>#}#").Title("Action");

})
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm concatenating a name and using a javascript function which made condition testing much easier, plus you can get access to multiple fields:

```
cshtml:
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Debtors>()
    .Name("Debtors")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c).Title("Name").ClientTemplate("#=showName(data)#");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Busname);
        ...
     })
    ...
)

js:
function showName(data) {
    var returnName = "";
    if (data.Lname) {
        returnName = data.Lname;
        if (data.Fname) {
            returnName += ", " + data.Fname;
            if (data.Mi) {
                returnName += " " + data.Mi;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnName;
}
```